# SQL - Create view from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

```
POP(country, year, pop)
FOOD(country, year, food)
INCOME(country, year, income)
```

I am trying to create a view such as:

```
V(country, year, pop, food, income)
```

This is my code so far. I don't think its correct:

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
(SELECT * FROM POP
UNION
SELECT * FROM FOOD
UNION
SELECT * FROM INCOME);
```

One issue is, a country that is present in `POP` may not be present in `FOOD`. Same goes for year. A year that is present in `POP` may not be present in `FOOD`. So, I keep thinking that the above code will not work.

Comment: It's rather off track. A union joins collates rows from multiple tables and/or queries that all have the same columns.

Comment: Your code isn't that bad, you're just a bit confused. On the upside, you know you're wrong and that's pretty important. Do any of the tables have a complete set of `country`/`year` pairs? And you should pick either MySQL or PostgreSQL in the tags, the solutions won't necessarily be the same for those two databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the help. This is what I ended up doing in order to make it work.

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
    SELECT *
    FROM ((POP NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN FOOD)
    NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN INCOME);
```

Answer (score 26):

Union is not what you want. You want to use joins to create single rows. It's a little unclear what constitutes a unique row in your tables and how they really relate to each other and it's also unclear if one table will have rows for every country in every year. But I think this will work:

```
CREATE VIEW V AS (

  SELECT i.country,i.year,p.pop,f.food,i.income FROM
    INCOME i
  LEFT JOIN 
    POP p 
  ON
    i.country=p.country
  LEFT JOIN
    Food f
  ON 
    i.country=f.country
  WHERE 
    i.year=p.year
  AND
    i.year=f.year
);
```

The left (outer) join will return rows from the first table even if there are no matches in the second. I've written this assuming you would have a row for every country for every year in the income table. If you don't things get a bit hairy as MySQL does not have built in support for FULL OUTER JOINs last I checked. There are ways to simulate it, and they would involve unions. This article goes into some depth on the subject: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 7):

This works too and you dont have to use join or anything:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS yourview;

CREATE VIEW yourview AS
    SELECT table1.column1, 
    table2.column2
FROM 
table1, table2 
WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`?

You want to use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) syntax, *not* UNION.  For example, using INNER JOIN:

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT POP.country, POP.year, POP.pop, FOOD.food, INCOME.income
FROM POP
INNER JOIN FOOD ON (POP.country=FOOD.country) AND (POP.year=FOOD.year)
INNER JOIN INCOME ON (POP.country=INCOME.country) AND (POP.year=INCOME.year)
```

However, this will only show results when each country and year are present in all three tables.  If this is not what you want, look into left outer joins (using the same link above).

Comment: Inner joins will not return all the rows they want as it was stated not all year & country combinations occur in all tables.