# Union SQL query troubles

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working with 3 tables: POV, Visit and Volume.

The main table I am basing myself on is POV which contains all main information from point of sales.

Volume contains for each point of sale, the volume of the last 2 years per product offered by the point of sale.

Visit contains the visit dates done in each point of sale.

What I would like to have is to have big table which would be like this:

```
POV columns   | Volumes columns | Visit columns

POV values    | Volume values   | Null
POV values    | null            | Visits
```

All tables have a column called 'povId' which contains the unique identifier of each point of sale. So I can use this to 'link' them all.

Could you please advise how I should proceed to obtain something like above?

I understand that a union would help but I'm not sure how to proceed. I want to have all point of sales from POV displayed (if for instance there is no data in VOlume, I want null).

Thank you a lot in advance! Cheers!

** Update ** Double left join code:

```
 Select * from (SELECT 
      [POV].[PovId] AS [PovId],
      [POV].[Last Visit Date] AS [Last Visit Date],
    [Visit].[VisitCode] as [VisitCode]
FROM [dbo].[POV] [POV]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Visit] [Visit] ON ([POV].[PovId] = [Visit].[PovId])) Tbl1 left join (  SELECT [POV].[PovId] AS [PovId2],
  [Volume].[Volume] AS [Volume],
  [Volume].[TMO] AS [TMO],
  [Volume].[Brand Family] AS [Brand Family]

FROM [dbo].[POV] [POV]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Volume] [Volume] ON ([POV].[PovId] = [Volume].[PovId])
where [Volume].[Year] between year(getdate())-1 and year(getdate())) Tbl2 on Tbl1.[PovId]=Tbl2.[PovId2]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you must post the code to help us understand and recreate the problem. Please see the help section to see how to ask question

Comment: Try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656864/sql-create-view-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Union is not the way to go. What you're trying to do is a `LEFT JOIN`.

From the `[LEFT JOIN][1]` documentation in MySQL:

> MySQL implements an A LEFT JOIN B join_condition as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> If there is a row in A that matches the WHERE clause, but there is no
>   row in B that matches the ON condition, an extra B row is generated
>   with all columns set to NULL.

You'll want to do something like:

```
SELECT POV.*, Visit.*, Volume.* FROM POV LEFT JOIN Visit ON POV.id = Visit.povId LEFT JOIN Volume ON POV.id = Volume.povId
```

Additional conditions might be added in the WHERE or in the LEFT JOIN condition, but be careful! Because the results might not be the same.

This being said, you'll want to improve the question by adding more information such as examples and so on. In this way, the entire community will take more advantage of the exchanges we have.

Comment: Dear all, Thank you for your answer.
I tried left joins but I do not get the same results when I compare the table I get when I do: POV left join Volume and POV left join Volume left join Visits....

I will add my code for the 'double' left join in the question description

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT 
      [POV].[PovId] AS [PovId],
      [POV].[Last Visit Date] AS [Last Visit Date],
      [Visit].[VisitCode] as [VisitCode]
  FROM [dbo].[POV] [POV]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Visit] [Visit] ON ([POV].[PovId] = [Visit].[PovId])
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Volume] [Volume] ON ([POV].[PovId] = [Volume].[PovId])
where [Volume].[Year] between year(getdate())-1 and year(getdate())
```

Comment: Hi Jayvee THanks a lot. The problem with this is that I need to sum on Volumes and with this table I get weird results. 
I managed to figure it out though by combining left joins and union :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I managed to get what I wanted.
I did a left join between POV and Visit, another one between POV and Volume and then a Union of the two. 
Worked perfect! Thank you all again!