# How can I have an array of tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL, and I have an excel spreadsheet I plan on moving into an SQL database. On most of the rows, there is a link to another associated spreadsheet(s). My idea for handling this is to have an array of tables as a column in the database (since there can be multiple associated tables)

If this is a decent idea, how do I implement that (how do I make an array of tables)?

If this is a bad idea, what would be a better way of doing this?

As requested, [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwxh.png) part of what the main spreadsheet looks like, and [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpm95.png) what part of one of the linked spreadsheets looks like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Create view from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656864/sql-create-view-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: @Claims I somehow doubt it

Comment: You are not a million miles away from a good idea. Take a look at a Database Design course for beginners. The array of tables in a column (was not good or possible) But another table linked to the first table etc etc is the right way to go

Comment: Bit hard to say what you should do based on the info provided, array of tables forces a wince out of me. Some example data would help.

Comment: SQL (mostly) does not have the concept of arrays - it has tables

Comment: I think that before do this you have to study a little about design and optimization of database. A couple of conceps of database design will be very useful for you. In addition if you have a difficult structure to modelize you can use a NoSQL database. All the decesions have pros and cons. For visualize the information you can do a query or (if you require it) a view, that is a fictional table create by the union of other tables.

Comment: In SQL, tables should not usually be dynamic entities. Rather than an array of tables, you put all the data in a single table, and use foreign keys as the links between tables.